# Makefile will link files upon a file change, but not recompile the source file that changed

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

I have the following makefile which seems to work pretty well:

```
HDRS =  include/config.h include/opcode_def.h include/x86lib.h include/x86lib_internal.h
CXX ?= g++
AR ?= ar


TEST_CC ?= i386-elf-gcc
TEST_CFLAGS ?= -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections


CXX_VM_SRC = vm/x86lib.cpp vm/modrm.cpp vm/device_manager.cpp vm/cpu_helpers.cpp vm/ops/strings.cpp vm/ops/store.cpp vm/ops/maths.cpp \
          vm/ops/groups.cpp vm/ops/flow.cpp vm/ops/flags.cpp vm/ops/etc.cpp

CXX_VM_OBJS = $(subst .cpp,.o,$(CXX_VM_SRC))

CXX_TESTBENCH_SRC = testbench/testbench.cpp

CXX_TESTBENCH_OBJS = $(subst .cpp,.o,$(CXX_TESTBENCH_SRC))


CXXFLAGS ?= -Wall -g3 -fexceptions -fPIC -Wall
CXXFLAGS += -DX86LIB_BUILD -I./include

VERSION=1.1

VM_OUTPUTS = libx86lib.a libx86lib.so.$(VERSION)
OUTPUTS = $(VM_OUTPUTS) x86testbench 

default: build

build: $(OUTPUTS)

libx86lib.a: $(CXX_VM_OBJS) $(CXX_VM_SRC)
    ar crs libx86lib.a $(CXX_VM_OBJS)

libx86lib.so.$(VERSION): $(CXX_VM_OBJS) $(CXX_VM_SRC)
    $(CXX) -shared $(CXX_VM_OBJS) -o libx86lib.so.$(VERSION)

x86testbench: $(CXX_TESTBENCH_OBJS) $(VM_OUTPUTS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -static -o x86testbench $(CXX_TESTBENCH_OBJS) -lx86lib -L.

$(CXX_TESTBENCH_OBJS): $(HDRS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $*.cpp -o $@

$(CXX_VM_OBJS): $(HDRS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $*.cpp -o $@

clean:
    rm $(CXX_VM_OBJS) $(OUTPUTS) $(CXX_TESTBENCH_OBJS)
```

My problem is that if I change a file, such as "vm/x86lib.cpp" then it will relink the final outputs and such, but it will not recompile vm/x86lib.o. I don't know how to express this recompile requirement to the `$(CXX_VM_OBJS)` build rule.

How do I fix this so that it will recompile my the source files as well as relink them?

Note: if I put `$(CXX_VM_SRC)` as a dependency on `$(CXX_VM_OBJS)`, then it will recompile every file anytime a single file changes. Also, I'm only concerned about GNU Make and OSX/Linux environments.

Answer (score 4):

As others have pointed out, the reason your makefile doesn't rebuild any object files when a source changes is that your rule:

```
$(CXX_VM_OBJS): $(HDRS)
    ...
```

doesn't mention that the source files are prerequisites. And the reason the proposed solution of adding them:

```
$(CXX_VM_OBJS): $(HDRS) $(CXX_VM_SRC)
    ...
```

causes Make to rebuild *all* source files when *any* source file changes, is that that is exactly what this rule demands. It makes *all* source files prerequisites of *any* object file.

The right way to handle this is with a [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern):

```
$(CXX_VM_OBJS): %.o: %.cpp $(HDRS)
    ...
```

And I would recommend the same for your `$(CXX_TESTBENCH_OBJS)` rule; even though it applies to only one object file now, it's clear that you are thinking of adding others later.

Answer (score 0):

In the dependency list for CXX_VM_OBJS, try to add the source filenames that you want the object to depend on, for example:

```
$(CXX_VM_OBJS): $(HDRS) vm/x86lib.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $*.cpp -o $@
```

Comment: this is the equivalent to just adding `$(CXX_VM_SRC)` to that rule